# Pods CPU getting Throttled even when CPU usage is less than requested

Tags: linux, kubernetes, cpu, throttling, cgroups

CPU is getting throttled even when the CPU usage for the container is below request.
From what I understand pods are scheduled at nodes where there is sufficient CPU available i.e what is requested.
First question here is let's say that this pod does not require this much cpu at a given time and some other pod wants to have more cpu (cpu requested will be under what is defined in limit) so will the other pod get it or will it be throttled?
Second question assuming if the answer is yes it will get the cpu, then let's say our pod wants to have more cpu now but other pod is already using it and there is not enough CPU left at node so will both the pods experience throttling or only the second pod will be throttled (From what I read pods are throttled when they ask more than limit) or a new node will be added to the cluster?

Or there can be some other reasons for this then please share your thoughts and recommend some good articles regarding this?

Also I read these 
https://medium.com/omio-engineering/cpu-limits-and-aggressive-throttling-in-kubernetes-c5b20bd8a718
But our version already has a fix for this so I think this is not what causing issue here.
https://medium.com/@betz.mark/understanding-resource-limits-in-kubernetes-cpu-time-9eff74d3161b

Comment: If there is anything not clear about the question please comment here.

Comment: Do you have any limits set up for containers? If you want your issue troubleshooted, please include your manifests.

Comment: I cannot share the complete manifest because there are many services, and yes limit is defined for each and every service.

Comment: But what is happening is some services cpu usage is even less than request but still they are getting throttled.

Comment: Still, it would help if you include at least the part with requests and limits, also event logs from throttled pods.

Answer (score 0):

There is an ongoing kuberenetes issue on how the CPU throttling problem caused by setting CPU limits is still ongoing in 5.4.0 Linux kernels. This might be related to your problems.
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/97445